# Convenient way to use CSS/SCSS modules within React App

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I really like CSS modules system and the easy way to import and use them in create-react-app. I also like the ability to nest classes in SCSS like this:

```css
.unit {
   .text {
      font-size: 0.8rem;
   }
}

.text {
  color: red;
}
```

But if I import these styles into my component and use them like this...

```js
import styles from './style.module.scss';

<div className={styles.unit}>
  <div className={styles.text}>small... and red!</div>
</div>

<div className={styles.text}>red</div>
```

...styles.text obviously will be the same class and the text in the "unit" div will be red, so if I don't want this inheritance I have to keep classes with the same names in separate files.

My qustion is: can I use this in better way somehow?
For e.g. I would be happy to use it like:

```js
<div className={styles.unit.text}></div>
```

But maybe I'm missing a better built-in solution or tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: dont do this. You should keep your style module really small and use only inside one component.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
import styles from './style.module.scss';
```

to

```
import './style.module.scss';
```

it should work

Since SCSS (and CSS!) files don't export anything, there's nothing specific to import so you want to import the whole file.